# Объясните else, находится между двух if, например, почему печатает 2 и не печатает 4? Почему не кидает ошибку? Работает код как надо!

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def is_prime():
    for num in range (1, 101):
        if num > 1:
            for i in range (2, num):
                if num % i == 0:
                    break           
            else:
                print(num)
is_prime()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops
Аналогично [гугл](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD+else+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5+%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0+for), первая же [ссылка на PythonWorld.ru, в конце про "волшебное" слово `else`](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/cikly-for-i-while-operatory-break-i-continue-volshebnoe-slovo-else.html)

Answer (score 3):

Это такой оригинальный питоновский синтаксис - for ... else. Да, этот else принадлежит к for. Если с цикла выйти по break - else не отработает. Если цикл завершится нормально, то else будет выполнятся.

Документация - https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

> Loop statements may have an else clause; it is executed when the loop terminates through exhaustion of the iterable (with for) or when the condition becomes false (with while), but not when the loop is terminated by a break statement. This is exemplified by the following loop, which searches for prime numbers:

и тут же приведен Ваш пример:)